# Selecting text in any text editor, then mousing over text, results in spin wheel hang of cursor

Tags: macos, mouse, text-editors

Very weird problem. When I [1] select text in any text editor (TextEdit, Bean or iA Writer) and then [2] hover over the highlighted text with my mouse cursor, I [3] get the spinning wheel of death cursor hang for about a second. To summarize, here are the steps which reproduce the problem:

- Open any text editor ...
- Select text (via keyboard, as in <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>arrow key</kbd>, or with cursor) ...
- Mouse hover over highlighted text ...
- ==> results in spinning wheel

Note that, this does *not* happen in a web browser. What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A restart of my machine resolved this issue.